# Какие запросы посылает клиент

Tags: c#

Здравствуй ХешКод! Вот решил сделать небольшой эмулятор сервера для одной игры, и когда начал делать, то наткнулся на одну проблему, вот допустим в игре появилась форма входа, надо ввести логин и пароль... Но вопрос, **что** должен отправить сервер клиенту чтобы клиент подумал что человек вошёл успешно? Как можно из клиента вытащить эти запросы?

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемый Csharp, на самом деле все проще.
Сервер клиенту должен отправлять именно то что было введено пользователем. А далее уже дело сервера решить вошел пользователь или нет. А это решение уже принимается на основе той информации что имеется на сервере (логины/пароли). И в результате как раз таки сообщение от сервера клиенту будет решающим и будет идентифицировать успешность входа в систему.

Comment: Вот, а как узнать что клиент должен ожидать от сервера, чтобы например успешно войти? Т.к я когда сделал небольшой серверок и просто посмотре что мне прислал клиент, там одни кракозябры, и что "ответить" клиенту я не знаю, как можно эту команду выковырять?

Answer (score 0):

Познакомьтесь с таким понятием как протокол. Если неизвестно, что и как сервер отправляет/принимает, ломать его можно довольно долго. Клиентские игры чаще всего с закрытыми для посторонних людей серверами, дабы artmoney не стал явью и для серверных игр ^_^. Самое "простое" в данном случае - откопать серверную часть, пожалуй.